# How to get post parameter in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm using Node.js express and httpAsyncClient library in android.

I was send request to express use Post include parameter.

Request is does work.
but I can't get parameter in Post

I used this  " var id = req.body.id; "

I think httpAsyncClient parameter type is form-data.
but express is handle x-www-form-urlencoded.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to configure a [body-parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). After that you should be able to get some results.